# How can I write two outputs to the same lines?

Tags: python, file

This is the bottom end of my code. The rest isn't really important, I'm just having trouble with the formatting. The values of i in df and ph are basically a bunch of lines with values. I need "\n" in the loop because I want all the data in the loop to be printed on new lines.

My problem is: The file I write to has the data from "df" printed below the data from "ph". I want them on the same lines together. I've thought of adding the data from "ph" to the beginning of "df" to combine them both but I feel there is an easier way to do this.

```
titration_curves = open('titration_curves.dat', 'w')

for i in residues:                     
    titration_curves.write("%s " % i)
titration_curves.write("\n")

for ph in ph_set:
    for i in ph:
        titration_curves.write("%s " % i)  
    titration_curves.write("\n")

for df in dfs:
    for i in df:                   
        titration_curves.write("%s  " % i)
    titration_curves.write("\n")
```

My output file looks like this:

```
2.0 
2.5 
3.0 
0.008  0.000  0.587  0.000  0.952  0.509  0.966  0.661  0.012  0.291  
0.065  0.000  0.517  0.000  0.848  1.000  0.938  0.939  0.034  0.226  
0.262  0.000  0.882  0.008  0.991  0.901  1.000  0.963  0.071  0.751
```

I want it to look like:

```
2.0 0.008  0.000  0.587  0.000  0.952  0.509  0.966  0.661  0.012  0.291
2.5 0.065  0.000  0.517  0.000  0.848  1.000  0.938  0.939  0.034  0.226 
3.0 0.262  0.000  0.882  0.008  0.991  0.901  1.000  0.963  0.071  0.751
```

Comment: try and play with `' '.format` for strings and `zip` for merging two loops into one, what you do there is horribly slow ;)

Comment: Is `residues`  `2.0 0.008  0.000  0.587  0.000  0.952  0.509  0.966  0.661  0.012  0.291` or `2.0 2.5 3.0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use python `zip` method to do it in one for loop:

```
for i,ph,df in zip(residues,ph_set,dfs):                     
    titration_curves.write("%s " % i)
    for j in ph:
        titration_curves.write("%s " % j)  
    for j in df:                   
        titration_curves.write("%s  " % j)
    titration_curves.write("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

To get them on the same line you will need to remove the line breaks `\n` and have the values you want on the same line share the same `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

If there are an equal number of values in ph and df, then use zip(), eg:

```
for ph_value, df_value in zip(ph, df):
    titration_curves.write('%s %s\n' % (ph_value, df_value))
```

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
>>> residues
['2.0', '0.008', '0.000', '0.587', '0.000', '0.952', '0.509', '0.966', '0.661', '0.012', '0.291']
>>> ph_set
['2.5', '0.065', '0.000', '0.517', '0.000', '0.848', '1.000', '0.938', '0.939', '0.034', '0.226']
>>> dfs
['3.0', '0.262', '0.000', '0.882', '0.008', '0.991', '0.901', '1.000', '0.963', '0.071', '0.751']
```

You can use `join`:

```
>>> print '\n'.join([' '.join(e) for e in (residues, ph_set, dfs)])
2.0 0.008 0.000 0.587 0.000 0.952 0.509 0.966 0.661 0.012 0.291
2.5 0.065 0.000 0.517 0.000 0.848 1.000 0.938 0.939 0.034 0.226
3.0 0.262 0.000 0.882 0.008 0.991 0.901 1.000 0.963 0.071 0.751
```